# How Do I find the Duration Between Observations for each By Group in SAS?

Tags: sas, lag, duration

I would like to calculate the duration between observations by group. So far I have tried using lags in a datastep with a by statement.  However this is not creating the results I want.

Assuming I start with Group and Date, how to I create a difference column as shown below?

Thanks!

```
    Group       Date       Difference
  Group 1    August 1         - 
  Group 1    August 3         2
  Group 1    August 6         3
  Group 1    August 10        4
  Group 2    Sept 1           -
  Group 2    September 20     19
  Group 2    September 25     5 
  Group 3     June 1          -
  Group 3     June 5          4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data want;
   set have;
   by group notsorted;
   difference=dif(date);
   if first.group then difference=.;
run;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few functions to get the desired result. As mentioned in a different answer, you can use the `dif` function which will return the `current_obs-previous_obs` in the dataset. Alternatively you can use the `retain` statement.

```
proc sort data=have;
by group date;
run;

data want(drop=last_date);
set have;
by group date;
retain last_date;
if first.date then Difference = .;
else Difference = date - last_date;
* Set the variable last_date equal to the current date;
last_date = date;
run;
```

If you omit the `drop=` the value of `last_date` will be the last value of date.